# showing content of an HTTP response in the browser without refreshing

Tags: c++, django, http

I am new to Django and I don't know if what I want is achievable this way.
I have a simple c++ client that has to send a char* array containing Json data using an HTTP request (post method) to my Django server(I use cpp-httplib to send HTTP request in c++).
The data is sent successfully the problem is I want to see the Json data in my browser as well but I have failed to do so.
Both client and server are running on the same machine and server is on localhost.
here is my **views.py**

```
def PostFunc(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    print(request.POST)
    print(request.body)
    result = request.body
    print(result)
    return HttpResponse(result)
```

my **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('',PostFunc),
]
```

and this is my **client code**

```
int main(){

Client cli("127.0.0.1",8000);

char* testJson = {"[{\"name\":\"Visual Studio Enterprise 2017\",\"version\":\"15.0.26228.4\"}]"};

auto res = cli.Post("/", testJson, "application/json");

cout << res->status;

system("pause");
return 0;
 }
```

Django version 3.0.8
Python 3.8.4rc1
Thank you for taking time to answer my question and let me know if any other information is needed.

Comment: What do you mean "see in browser"? This is a C++ client, not a browser.

Comment: You should make a new 'GET' request in django that just displays a simple 'Hello world' html page. Something at `/hi`. When you visit `127.0.0.1:8000/hi` in your web browser. Once you have that, you need a way to store `request.body` to a variable, and replace 'Hello world' with this string in the GET method.

Comment: @tadman I want to see the response returned from views.py in 127.0.0.1:8000 but I realized that refreshing the url sends a GET request so I cant see the response

Comment: @SpentDeath Thank you for your insight.I think combining this with JsonResponse as AnoopKGoerge suggested will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I'm posting what worked for me just in case someone has the same issue.
For my specific need I found using templates more convenient.
And as mentioned in the comments,after the POST request a Get request will get the result for you by redirecting to the same URL.
**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        recv = request.POST.get('key')
        print(recv)
        ListProgram.objects.create(name=recv)
        return redirect(request.path)
    else:
        obj = ListProgram.objects.all()
        return render(request,'list/response.html',{'message':obj})
```

**response.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  {% load static %}
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="{% static "list/styleResponse.css" %}"/>
  <title>HTTP RESPONSE</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>response changed</h3>
  {% if message %}
      <textarea rows="5" cols="35">
          {% for s in message %}
            key:{{s}}
          {% endfor %}
      </textarea>
  {% else %}
  <p>No data is available.</p>
  {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

Would appreciate any suggestion on how to improve this as I'm a beginner!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deal with Django through Json objects, try to send objects as Json and return objects as Json.

```
Usage
Typical usage could look like:

>>> from django.http import JsonResponse
>>> response = JsonResponse({'foo': 'bar'})
>>> response.content
b'{"foo": "bar"}'
```

Also, when you POST objects to Django try to exempt views from csrf token for test purpose.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')
```

The Djano rest framework is dedicated to handle Json objects learn more https://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: Thank you for your valuable insight I will give it a try.